# How to scp all files of a certain owner?

Tags: shell, files, scp

I want to scp all files of certain owners. For example, if this is my `ls -la` output:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 owner1 ad   704 Jun  1 18:16 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 owner2 ad   798 May 29 11:15 file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 owner2 ad   881 May 29 09:28 file3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 owner3 ad   936 May 29 09:28 file4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 owner1 ad  1012 Jun  1 15:14 file5
```

I would like to scp all files of owner 1 and 3, so `file1`, `file4`, and `file5`.

Is there something like

```
scp login@some.cluster.nl:/path/to/folder/* . --owner owner1 owner2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient and safe way is probably `find | tar | tar`:

```
ssh login@some.cluster.nl 'cd /path/to/folder; find . \( -user owner1 -o -user owner3 \) -print0 | tar --null -T - -cf -' | tar -xvf -
```

You'd better review the tar archive content before extracting it.  Replace last `| tar -xvf -` to `| tar -tvf -` and run to get the file list.

Comment: If you don't have the same users locally as on the remote system, you will end up with file with correct uid's but name changes or missing. But I do like the use of tar instead of scp, seems less resource hungry using a stream across the established connection and -z option could be added for compression.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether there is shorter command/method to do it, but this will work:

```
for i in * ; do [[ $(stat -c %U ./"$i") =~ owner1|owner3 ]] && scp -p login@some.cluster.nl:/path/to/folder/ ./"$i"  ; done
```

It uses the `stat -c %U` on all the files in the current directory to check their owners and proceeds to `scp` the file if the owner is owner1 or owner3.

Comment: You are going to fail (because missing `-r`) multiple times to copy the whole of remote folder `/path/to/folder`...

Comment: @yaegashi , I think that was self explanatory. The user is free to use as many options as he wants with the `scp`. The OP was about files.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote server supports SFTP and the client allows [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), then mount the remote directory over [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). You can then work without having to worry about local vs remote files: they'll all be files.

```
mkdir ~/mnt
sshfs login@some.cluster.nl:/path/to/folder ~/mnt
```

Now you need to copy the files owned by certain users to the `~/mnt` directory.  To do this for all files in the current directory (but not in subdirectories):

```
find . -name . -o -type d -prune -o \( -user owner1 -o owner3 \) -exec cp -p {} ~/mnt \;
```

To traverse the current directory recursively, and put all files in the target directory, prompting if there are name collisions:

```
find . \( -user owner1 -o owner3 \) -exec cp -ip {} ~/mnt \;
```

To traverse the current directory recursively, and reproduce the directory tree on the other side, you can use one of:

```
find . \( -user owner1 -o owner3 \) -print0 | cpio -p0 ~/mnt
find . \( -user owner1 -o owner3 \) -exec pax -rw -pe {} ~/mnt \;
```

It's simpler if you have zsh, because there you can select files by owner with a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
cp -p -- *(uowner1,uowner3) ~/mnt                   # not recursive
cp -ip -- **/*(uowner1,uowner3) ~/mnt               # recursive, flattened
zmv -C -Q -o-p '**/*(uowner1,uowner3)' '~/mnt/$f'   # reproduce tree
```

When you've finished working with the remote files, unmount the filesystem.

```
fusermount -u `/mnt
rmdir ~/mnt
```